# Why does it say this when I open a text file, "argument should be integer or None, not 'str'"

Tags: python, file, text

why does my code say `argument should be integer or None, not 'str'` when the text file I store in note is just a string. What should I do to open an integer note?.

```
f = open("testpoem.txt")
# e.g., f = open("data2.txt")
text = f.read("testpoem.txt")
# text is a string that contains the contents of the entire file
    
# problem 1
def string2list(text):
    return text.split()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(string2list(text))
```

Here is the full error

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\filetest.py", line 3, in  text = f.read("testpoem.txt")
> TypeError: argument should be integer or None, not 'str'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because read accepte only one argument (size) which "Optional. The number of bytes to return. Default -1, which means the whole file."

So your code should be:

```
f = open("testpoem.txt", 'r' )
# e.g., f = open("data2.txt")
text = f.read()
```

Comment: is there any code that let me slit at a comma("."), not at every space.

Comment: Not sure to understand what you except (espacially without knowing content of your file). But if you are looking to Split a string which contains many sentence to a list which contain every sentence you can try mytext.split(".") => where mytext is the name of the string you Want to Split by sentence.